# Left and right multiplication of a matrix A with an upper triangular matrix U

Tags: matrices

Let A and $U$ are two square matrices where A is invertible. If
$$AU=UA$$
In partitioned form 
$$\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}&A_{12}\\A_{21}&A_{22}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}U_{11}&0_{12}\\0_{21}&U_{22}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}U_{11}&0_{12}\\0_{21}&U_{22}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}&A_{12}\\A_{21}&A_{22}\end{bmatrix}$$
$\implies$
$$A_{21}U_{11}=U_{22}A_{21}$$
where $U_{11}$ and $U_{22}$ are upper triangular square matrices (dimension can be different) and **$U_{11}$ and $U_{22}$ cannot have same diagonal elements**

**Then how to prove $A_{21}$ is a zero matrix** and similarly $A_{12}$

Comment: Why do you think $A$ is zero? What if $U_1$ and $U_2$ are identity matrices?

Comment: Edited. I was trying to make the question simple, but lost major points. Thanks for notifying